# EyelidFieldManager does not display bottom dock

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I'm using an `EyelidFieldManager` on a `MainScreen` of my Blackberry app. Here is the code

```
EyelidFieldManager manager = new EyelidFieldManager();

HorizontalFieldManager buttonFieldSet = new HorizontalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
buttonFieldSet.addAll(new ButtonField[] {new ButtonField("One"), new ButtonField("Two"), new ButtonField("Three")});

manager.addBottom(buttonFieldSet);
manager.setEyelidDisplayTime(3000);

add(manager);
```

Nothing gets shown at the bottom of the screen but when I change the line `manager.addBottom(buttonFieldSet)` to `manager.addTop(buttonFieldSet)` the `HorizontalFieldManager` gets displayed at the Top.

Why does this happen? Why is the `EyelidFieldManager` able to show the `HorizontalFieldManager` when it's docked at the top but not when its docked at the bottom.

Comment: refer this http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2012/04/display-toolbar-with-auto-closing.html

Comment: Changes noting, I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: try with setStatus(bottomEyelidFieldManager);

Comment: I'll prefer is the container is not permanently displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey even i have been presently working with the eyelid field manager and i am getting the bottom dock perfectly.
Check this

```
     // Add components to the south eye-lid of the blinker
    _eyelidFieldManager.addBottom(new LabelField(" Send Report as: ",LabelField.FIELD_HCENTER | LabelField.NON_FOCUSABLE));
    HorizontalFieldManager buttonPanel = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
    buttonPanel.add(new ButtonField("One"));
    buttonPanel.add(new ButtonField("Two"));
    buttonPanel.add(new SimpleButton("Three"));
    _eyelidFieldManager.addBottom(buttonPanel);
```

Eyelid Field manager has been defined like this:

```
    private EyelidFieldManager _eyelidFieldManager;
```

and then this  _eyelidFieldManager = new EyelidFieldManager();

You can refer to my complete code here where i have tried using them within tabs
[Usage of vertical field manager with eyelid field manager in blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584284/usage-of-vertical-field-manager-with-eyelid-field-manager-in-blackberry)
Hope it helps.